# IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range when i pinchzoom the image

Tags: android, image, pinchzoom

I have added pinchzoom.jar library to my project to allow pinching and zooming of images.And added the following code-

```
try {
                    usingSimpleImage(imageView);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                }

 public void usingSimpleImage (ImageView imageView){
        try {
            ImageAttacher mAttacher = new ImageAttacher(imageView);
            // ImageAttacher.MAX_ZOOM = 2.0f; // Double the current Size
            //  ImageAttacher.MIN_ZOOM = 0.5f; // Half the current Size
            MatrixChangeListener mMaListener = new MatrixChangeListener();
            mAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(mMaListener);
            PhotoTapListener mPhotoTap = new PhotoTapListener();
            mAttacher.setOnPhotoTapListener(mPhotoTap);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
    }


    private class PhotoTapListener implements OnPhotoTapListener {

        @Override
        public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {
        }
    }

    private class MatrixChangeListener implements OnMatrixChangedListener {

        @Override
        public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {

        }
    }
```

I got the following exception  sometimes when i fastly pinch and zoom and my app crashes-

```
Exception dispatching input event.
10-11 19:31:10.734  31507-31507/com.peoplecloud.guggu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
            at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
            at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1981)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:91)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:219)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1839)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1833)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1938)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1392)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2408)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7323)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3521)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4523)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4619)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4638)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:534)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible facing the same issue as https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/4.

The workaround is to try-catch the error:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```